# Make a query on a JSON database in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to get elements from a local `JSON` database and I have the following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-md-12" id="app2">
            {{ database }}
        </div>
        <script>
            function httpGet(theUrl){
                var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
                xmlHttp.send(null);
                return xmlHttp.responseText;
            }

        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app2 = new Vue({
                el: '#app2',
                data: {
                    database: httpGet("http://a6b4a4a271.testurl.ws/metadata/")
                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So now I need to display information in my database in the variable "database" and not display the entire database.

Comment: You may need to call `JSON.parse` on the return value of `httpGet` to convert to JSON then use [`v-for` directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html?#v-for-with-an-Object)

Comment: Excuse me but this isn't really clear you mean something like this  ? : return JSON.parse(httpGet("http://a6b4a4a271.testurl.ws/metadata/"))

Comment: Yeah, that should work seeing that your `XmlHttpRequest` is synchronous

Comment: Okay thanks you it works !